# Phonegap FileTransfer and JQuery Mobile JSON Response

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

i need some help fom the experts.

I want upload a picture to my php script and it works.
Now, i want get back a JSON Response after upload to my div #showdata, but it don't work :(

### Start Transfer Upload

```
     var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                options.fileKey="file";
                options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

                var params = new Object();
                params.message = pmsg;
                options.params = params;
                options.chunkedMode = false;
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, server, function(r) {
        document.getElementById('camera').innerHTML = "Upload successful: "+r.bytesSent+" bytes uploaded.";  
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

 // here get the Json response

    $('#showdata').html("<p>item1="+r.item1+" item2="+r.item2+" item3="+r.item3+"</p>");}, function(error) {
    document.getElementById('camera').innerHTML = "Upload failed: Code = "+error.code;              
    }, options); }
```

Can you help me, how i display the JSON results.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in your success function you get an [FileUploadResult](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.1/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileUploadResult) which you have referred to as "f". Well f has a property called "response" which gives you the response from the PHP page. You'll have to look at the response and use JSON.parse() to turn it into and Object.

Answer (score 0):

the response from the server PHP page:

```
return json_encode(array('item1'=>'value1', 'item2'=>'value2'));
```

parse FileUploadResult in javascript:

```
try {
    var obj = JSON.parse(FileUploadResult.response); // Produces a SyntaxError
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message); // Handle the error - Unexpected token
}
```

try using eval:

```
eval('var obj=' + FileUploadResult.response);
```